# Active Record Query scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a pie Chart with variables i get from a Loop:

```
<% @something.cool.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.foo %>
<% end %>
```

The output of this Loop is e.g.:

```
55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 55
```

That means almost `95% is 55's` and `5% are 45's`.

So basically i need a way for Rails to find the variable groups (55, 45) and count them so i can show the percentage of the groups.

The options i can pass on my pie chart (JS) look like this:

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
          ['Firefox',   45.0],
          ['IE',       26.8],
          ['Chrome', 12.8],
          ['Safari',    8.5],
          ['Opera',     6.2],
          ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
      }]
```

How can i scope this properly so i can use it in my Chart?

Comment: you example does not make sense -- please redefine your question with proper example / data !

Comment: Edited my Question, maybe you can understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enumerable#`group_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) is your friend:

```
grouped = [55, 45, 55, 55, 55, 45, 12].group_by { |e| e }
grouped.each do |in_common, occurences|
  puts "There is #{occurences.size} occurences for the word '#{in_common}'\n"
end
```

It tells you the amount of occurences for each number.

---

**In your case**, with the percent calculation:

```
results = [55, 45, 55, 55, 55, 45, 12]
@grouped = results.group_by { |e| e }

series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
          <% @grouped.each do |legend, values| %>
            <%= "['#{legend}', #{values.size}]," %>
          <% end %>
        ]
      }]
```

Comment: Hey Yoshi, do you know why i'm getting an encoding error when trying this? The apostrophes are getting translated to `&#39;55&#39;` When i'm using it in my view it works fine, but as soon i try it in JS it doesn't convert it.

Comment: you need to use `escape_javascript` block, or its short version: `<%=j "['#{legend}', #{values.size}]," %>` (notice the `j` function)